# Htaccess url redirecting error

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following structure in my htaccess file. My issue is if URI matches with condition URL redirect according to rule and if URI doesn't match default rule should apply, please tell me how to fix.

First Rule: `RedirectMatch 301 /mob/(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/price/$1`

Default Rule: `RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1`

when I tried this default rule overriding other rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming both domains are on the same root folder and host:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^originaldomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://differentdomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
If they are not on the same root and folder:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://differentdomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
Now the 2nd part if the url is not a act, url, system or post:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(act\?(.*)|url|system)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://originaldomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
Basically this should work, if it does after you test change to 302 to 301 if needed.
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for response but here domains are different and host also.

Comment: redirect to localhost